# sql syntax error due to double backslash in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm writing code using Python to connect Postgresql.

When I try to copy the CSV file to SQL table, the syntax is '\copy TABLE_NAME from PATH_OF_FILE delimiter ',' csv header;

the '\' make the error when I execute the sql query.
Because it will become '\\copy'

Is there any way I can get rid of this '\\' ??

```
def copy_file(file_name, table, path):

    copy_csv = '\copy ' + table +''' from '''+  "'" + path + "/" + file_name + "'" + ''' delimiter ',' csv header;'''
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(copy_csv)
        connection.commit()
        answer = "Data successfully loaded in PostgreSQL"
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
        answer = "Error while Inserting Data into PostgreSQL table: " + str(error)
    return answer
```

I expect the output is `\copy table from path....`,
but the actual output is `\\copy table from path...`

Comment: What is the exact actual error?

Comment: do you get error ? you may use prefix `r` (raw) to create `r"\copy"`

Comment: In general Python displays (not prints) backslashes in escaped form as double backslashes.

Comment: 'Error while Inserting Data into PostgreSQL table: syntax error at or near "\\"\nLINE 1: \\copy table from \'/home/file.csv\' ...\n        ^\n'

Comment: I know it displays escaped form but the only error I found was in \\\\ backslash problem, I tried it manually. It works without the double \\\\

Comment: I also tried copy_csv = r"\copy " + table +''' from '''+  "'" + path + "/" + file_name + "'" + ''' delimiter ',' csv header;''' but it pops up the same error

Answer (score 0):

Why you need the `\` at the beginning? Try this:

```
import os


def copy_file(file_name, table, path):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            f"copy {table} from %(filepath}s delimiter ',' csv header",
            {"filepath": os.path.join(path, file_name)}
        )
        connection.commit()
        answer = "Data successfully loaded in PostgreSQL"
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
        answer = "Error while Inserting Data into PostgreSQL table: " + str(error)
    return answer
```

This uses:

- f-Strings to build the string (This is support since python3.6)
- the os module to join path name and filename
- named parameter in the query

**EDIT:**

Instead of f-Strings it its more save to use [SQL string composition](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql).

```
import os
from psycopg2 import sql

def copy_file(file_name, table, path):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            sql.SQL("copy {} from %(filepath}s delimiter ',' csv header").format(sql.Identifier(table)),
            {"filepath": os.path.join(path, file_name)}
        )
        connection.commit()
        answer = "Data successfully loaded in PostgreSQL"
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
        answer = "Error while Inserting Data into PostgreSQL table: " + str(error)
    return answer
```

Comment: Because I'm using the cluster which is university provided. If I only use copy, then the error will be must be superuser to COPY to or from a file\nHINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \\copy command also works for anyone.\n

Comment: Thank you for the information, the logic of the code is much clear. But the problem hasn't solved Error while Inserting Data into PostgreSQL table: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file\nHINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \\copy command also works for anyone.\n This is Why I use \\copy

Comment: I tried to use copy_from, when I open the file and sep=',' one column value contains the comma, so it ends up with the extra column. Then I try another way